# How to assign promise to scope

Tags: angularjs, restangular

How to assign $promise to $scope.advertiserName? In the below example, Console.log($scope.title) returns "undefined".

```
 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
   $scope.advertiserName = data.name;
   $scope.advertiserId = data.id;
 });

 $scope.title = $scope.advertiserName;
 $scope.id = $scope.advertiserId;
```

Comment: It's not even clear what you're asking. You want to assign the `$promise` to `advertiserName`? Right now you're already, presumably, properly assigning the result to `advertiserName`; what's the issue here?

Answer (score 3):

We can use callback function to execute lines of code after getting response of ajax call.You can visit this blog for awesome explanation of call back function http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/. Lets understand it through code.

```
    $scope.setNameId = function (title,id,callBackFunction) {
     Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
      // $scope.advertiserName = data.name;
       $scope.title= data.name;
      // $scope.advertiserId = data.id;
       $scope.id=data.id;
       callBackFunction();
     });
    }
     $scope.setNameId($scope.title,$scope.id,executeAfterResponse);
    var executeAfterResponse=function(){
    //code that you want to execute when value of $scope.title and $scope.id has changed
    };
```

We can also do it by this approach

```
$scope.setNameId(executeAfterResponse);
```

Without passing `$scope.title` and `$scope.id` variable in argument of `$scope.setNameId` function as `$scope` variables can be accessed directly inside same file.

Commented lines of code are not required as we are assigning value to `$scope.name` and `$scope.id` directly.

Answer (score 1):

If I am getting you correct, this is happening because of asynchronous call.

> **Asynchronous** means sending the request (or rather receiving the response) is taken out of the normal execution flow. In your example,
>   $.ajax returns immediately and the next statement, return result;, is
>   executed before the function you passed as success callback was even
>   called.

You should do it like

```
$scope.someFunction = function () {
 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
   return $scope.advertiserName = data.name;
 });
}
$scope.title = $scope.someFunction(); //It will give you output
```

**Edit 1:**

I read many articles for the same and what I noticed that the response of `asynchronous` call will be taken out from normal execution flow. Either you use `restangule` or `$http` call, both are `asynchronous` call. So compiler will not wait for your response. You need to tell the compiler to wait for the ajax response. What I did in one of my projects. Here is a simple example which may illustrate more.

First I declared a controller function. Like below

```
$scope.asynchronousCallee = function (){
 $http.get('/url').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.myAjaData = data;
  });
}

$scope.asynchronousCallee(); //Call above function just after the declaration
```

Simply this function will receive data from server with a `get` call and assign response in variable but please note this success function will be called `asynchronously`. So what I did, I called `asynchronousCallee` function just after the declaration of it. Now compiler will wait for the response of this function and after executing the function, compiler will proceed further. I hope it may help you brother :-)

Comment: I actually looking for synchronous call as you said. Thanks Vineet. But $scope.title is getting executed before the $scope.someFunction is completed.  I also would like to execute code next to scope.title after $scope.scomeFunction is executed.

Comment: @Inaccessible, check this out my edited answer. It's working for me very well. I hope it will work for you too :-)

Answer (score 1):

In your example below you are expecting the memory reference of advertiserName and title and advertiserId and id to be maintained.  However, when pulling properties off of the scope it is retrieved by value not by reference.  If you wanted to make your code work you would have to do one of two things:

```
 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
   $scope.advertiserName = data.name;
   $scope.advertiserId = data.id;
 });

 $scope.title = $scope.advertiserName;
 $scope.id = $scope.advertiserId;
```

Initialize the correct property on the scope:

```
 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
     $scope.title = data.name;
     $scope.id = data.id;
 });
```

Make it a by reference update instead:

```
 var advertiser = {
     id: $scope.advertiser,
     title: $scope.advertiser
 }
 $scope.advertiser = advertiser;

 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
     advertiser.title = data.name;
     advertiser.id = data.id;
 });
```

Since promises through the use of angular already trigger a digest cycle the view will then be updated

Answer (score 0):

```
 Restangular.all('advertiser').one("?id=" + 1).getList().then(function(data) {
   $scope.advertiserName = data.name;
   $scope.advertiserId = data.id;
    return { name : data.name, id : data.id };
 }, function(er){
    //Handle error
 })
.then(function(response){
  $scope.title = response.name;
  $scope.id = response.id;
}, function(er){
  //Handle error
});
```